# How to Make a Dynamic Nav-Bar with Evenly Separated Links and Parent Containers (React/CSS)

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm basically trying to replicate the Twitter profile navbar with the profile links: `["Posts", "Posts & replies", "Media", "Likes"]`.

my current problem code: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-blackwell-mjjpg?file=/src/App.js

My Constraints:

1.) The navbars link text must be equally distanced from each other on both the left and right sides at all times during viewport width size changes.

2.) The navbar must be centered in its container and its links must be centered within their containers while both the far left and far right sides must be evenly distanced from the edge of the container so that the left and the right distance from the edge of the container is the same as the distance each link is separated.

Heres an example:

[image]

Currently, my links aren't separated equally, and I'm not exactly sure how to replicate Twitters profile nav style.

[image: links not seperated equally]

I've tested Material-UIs bottomNavBar styles and it doesn't replicate Twitter. [mui bottom nav bar](https://material-ui.com/components/bottom-navigation/)

MUI Nav bar not equally spaced:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, it was pretty simple. Instead of using CSS flex to layout my links, I used CSS grid instead. Somehow grid naturally allows elements to do this behavior without extra css. Interestingly I noticed Twitter uses flex, but here's the result:

fixed code: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-blackwell-mjjpg?file=/src/App.js

As you can see, now the links, containers, and sides are perfectly centered and distanced apart!

[image]